# How can the two diagrams in definition of monad be written as identity equations?

Tags: category-theory, monads

Categories for the Working Mathematician says

> Definition.  A  monad  $T= \langle T, \eta, \mu\rangle $  in  a  category  $X$ 
>   consists  of a  functor  $T: X \to X$  and  two  natural
>   transformations
>
> $$\eta  : I_X \Rightarrow T,  \mu : T^2 \Rightarrow T  $$
>
> which  make the following  diagrams  commute
>
> [image]

How can  the two diagrams in (2) be written as identity equations?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In any diagram: pick two objects $x,y$, list all 'morphism paths' that start in $x$ and end in $y$. All these compositions ought to be equal. This is rather direct for commuting squares and triangles, since we have few paths to consider. Here, we have

$$
\mu \circ T\mu  = \mu \circ \mu T
$$

and

$$\mu \circ \eta T = \mu \circ T\eta = 1_T.$$

Comment: Thanks. Do the identity equations not depend on the operands: $T^3, T^2, T, IT, TI$?

Comment: I dont' know what do you mean by operand here. These are the domains and codomains of each arrow, they implicit in their composition. More importantly, $T$ is fixed: the mondad is the $3$-uple $(T,\mu,\eta)$.

Comment: Why do your identity equations not specify what $\mu, T\mu, \mu T, \eta T, T \eta$ apply to

Comment: That's implicit from the definition: the multiplication is an arrow $\mu : T^2 \Rightarrow T$ and the unit is an arrow $\eta : 1_T \Rightarrow T$. From these fact one can deduce the (co)domain of all the other arrows.

Comment: Thanks. Why is $\mu$ called multiplication and $\eta$ unit? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3302168/why-are-the-two-natural-transformations-in-the-definition-of-monad-called-the-un

Comment: If I may, another question. $\eta(I_X)=T$ and $T \circ I_X = T$, so is $\eta$ the same as $T \circ$? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3295637/given-eta-i-x-rightarrow-t-is-eta-just-t