# Why are the two natural transformations in the definition of monad called the unity and multiplication?

Tags: category-theory, monads

Categories for the Working Mathematician says

> Definition.  A  monad  $T= \langle T, \eta, \mu\rangle $  in  a  category  $X$
> consists  of a  functor  $T: X \to X$  and  two  natural
> transformations
>
> $$\eta  : I_X \Rightarrow T,  \mu : T^2 \Rightarrow T  $$
>
> which  make the following  diagrams  commute
>
> [image]
>
> We  shall  thus  call  $\eta$
> the unit and $\mu$  the  multiplication of the monad $T$;  the first commutative
> diagram of (2) is then the associative law for the monad, while the second
> and  third  diagrams  express  the  left  and  right  unit  laws,  respectively.

Why is $\eta$ called the unity, and $\mu$ multiplication?

How is the first diagram the associative law?  It says $μ∘Tμ=μ∘μT$, which equates $Tμ$ and $μT$ up to $μ$, so seems to me the commutative law instead.

Why are the second and third diagrams the second the left and right unit laws? They say that $μ∘ηT=μ∘Tη=1_T$, They seem to me that $ηT$ and $Tη$ are the same up to $\mu$ and they are both inverse of $μ$.

Thanks.

Comment: You might consider looking up *string diagrams*, which I think make it clearer.  For example, https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monad and http://www.stephendiehl.com/posts/monads.html have some pictures.

Comment: Analogy with monoids?

Answer (score 6):

Given a category $\mathcal C$, the category $[\mathcal C,\mathcal C]$ of endofunctor is naturally a (non symmetric) strict monoidal category: the tensor product is the composition, the unit object if the identity functor and the associators and unitors are actual identities.

A monad on $\mathcal C$ is exactly a monoid in this monoidal category $[\mathcal C,\mathcal C]$.

Comment: Thanks. In the category [C,C] of endofunctor, "the unit object is the identity functor and the associators and unitors are actual identities." But I am asking in the monad  T=⟨T,η,μ⟩ in a category X (i.e. your C), why is η called the unity, and μ multiplication? η isn't the identity functor, and μ isn't the composition between functors.

Comment: Some other questions. (2) How is the first diagram the associative law? It says $μ∘Tμ=μ∘μT$, which equates $Tμ$ and $μT$ up to $μ$, so seems to me the commutative law instead.
(3) Why are the second and third diagrams the second the left and right unit laws? They say that $μ∘ηT=μ∘Tη=1_T$, They seem to me that $ηT$ and $Tη$ are both inverse of $\mu$.

Comment: A *monoid object* $C$ in a monoidal category $(\mathcal C, \otimes, I)$ has unit $I\to C$ and composition $C\otimes C\to C$, satisfying the same diagrams. Consider first what it means in $(Set,\times,\{*\})$, and then in $([\mathcal C,\mathcal C],\,\circ,\,id_{\mathcal C}) $.